# Texmaker crashes when typing any word with the letters d-a in sequence

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu

I am experimenting a weird crash on `Texmaker`. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and, surprisingly, I experience the same issue on my old computer (Ubuntu 18.04).

Whenever I am typing a word containing the sequence d-a (in French that often occurs in the word '**da**ns', in English in to**da**y etc.), `Texmaker` freezes first (unable to save when it happens), then crashes.

When I start `Texmaker` again, not only is the unsaved part lost, but also my compilation settings are back to an older setting, which I find really annoying. (I have to change settings frequently because some of the people I work with use .pdf and others .ps and compile with `XeLaTeX`).

I cannot send you a relevant log file because it is crashing without compiling … I do send the Ubuntu error report to whoever receives it. Here it is (thanks to @marijn ):

> ERROR: apport (pid 5685) Mon Jun 20 08:47:26 2022: called for pid 4033, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
> ERROR: apport (pid 5685) Mon Jun 20 08:47:26 2022: executable: /usr/bin/texmaker (command line "texmaker /home/guillaume/Nextcloud/universeh/Cours/Conf1-mesopotamie/Babylon_Universeh.tex")
> ERROR: apport (pid 5685) Mon Jun 20 08:47:26 2022: is_closing_session(): Could not determine DBUS socket.
> ERROR: apport (pid 5685) Mon Jun 20 08:47:38 2022: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_texmaker.1000.crash
> ERROR: apport (pid 67684) Mon Jun 20 22:02:13 2022: executable was modified after program start, ignoring

I am now quite used to this phenomenon (it was already there at least six years ago), but I am a bit disappointed that it happens again with a brand new config.

Comment: It sounds like a really strange bug indeed. Maybe it is related to some autocomplete functionality, or a spell checker? You could try to disable those. For the crash report: the dialog where you can choose to send the report also contains a 'Show details' button, you can trigger the crash again and copy from there. Alternatively, previous crash reports are stored on your computer in `/var/log/apport.log`, `apport.log.1`, `.2.gz` etc.

Comment: you are using since 6 years an application that has a reproducible bug that leads to lost of data?? Did you report that to the texmaker maintainer? If yes and if they didn't correct this, why didn't you switch to some more reliable editor?

Comment: Obviously whatever it is isn't very common. Does it happen with other qt apps on Ubuntu; try texstudio or focuswriter, for example.

Comment: I don't know if it is related but from the file path in the crash report it seems that the document is stored in the cloud, this is sometimes the reason for unexpected behavior. You could try storing the document locally and check if the problem persists.